dynamically include or exclude capacitor plugins in a quasar webpack or vite project
I am trying to build an app that will both  have a web spa and android apk. I am using quasar  cli with webpack (also have an alternate with vite). I am using webpack since I could use require, I know I can use await import("src_to_some_module") too.
I have used mounted hook to load a splash-screen but I would like this feature only on capacitor project and not on my spa
*async mounted() {
    console.log("platform ", Platform.is.desktop);
    if (!Platform.is.mobile) return;
    console.log("below return ===");
    const { SplashScreen } = require('@capacitor/splash-screen');
    await SplashScreen.show({
      showDuration: 10000,
      autoHide: true,
      splashFullScreen: true
    });
  }*

I am using quasar platform detection api to load the splash-screen plugin. I am however getting  module not found for @capacitor/splash-screen which I installed in the src-capacitor folder.
How can I use either vite or webpack to check say from an env variables (I have also added cross-env package just to add some env variables like MODE=spa or MODE=capacitor to the scripts to run the project either in capacitor or spa modes
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
    "dev": "cross-env MODE=spa quasar dev",
    "android": "cross-env MODE=capacitor quasar dev -m capacitor -T android --ide",
    "build": "quasar build"
  },

)
I would like to completely ignore any module starting with "@capacitor" from being loaded either in dev or build when MODE is spa. Below is the quasar config attempt to do it but it fails to ignore
  chainWebpack(chain) {
        console.log("process.env. ======== ", process.env.MODE);
        if (process.env.MODE !== 'capacitor') {
          chain.module
            .rule('external')
            .test(/^@capacitor/)
            .exclude.add(/node_modules/)
            .end()
            .use('null-loader')
            .loader('null-loader');
        }
      },

